# Convert a numpy 2D array to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an array

```
r = np.zeros((5,6))
print r
```

whose output is

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

I want to assign the values in this array to a list 
so I created a list by name grid

```
grid1 = [['a' for i in range (0,6)]  for j in range (0,5)]
print grid1
```

whose output is

```
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
```

How can I assign each value in the array to the corresponding location in list using a for loop?

I am using python 2.7

Output should be:

```
 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: So, you just want to convert a numpy 2d array to a list of lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
r = np.zeros((5,6))
lst = r.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version, using for loops and two arrays, concatenating from the numpy array to the python list element by element:

```
listed = []
temp = []
r = np.zeros((5,6))

for i in r:
   for j in i:
     temp += [int(j)]
   listed += [temp]
   temp = []

print listed
```

`listed` returns

```
[
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

...as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Didnt fully understand. Is this what your looking for?

```
numbers = []
  for array in r:
    for arrayj in array:
        numbers.append(arrayj)
```

Comment: i need output in this form sir
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] rather than [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] which is ur codes output